# send an array with jquery $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

i am trying to pass an array to ajax.Here is the code (productOptions is the ARRAY)

```
data: { action:'add',tblID : tblID, option:productOptions},
```

as far as i know whith this approach (using objects) jquery do the job BUT i dont get the option parameter at all (EXPLAIN BELOW).

NOTICE :

```
var productOptions=new Array();
    productOptions[0]="test1";
    productOptions[1]="test2";
```

with the above array i get the productOptions

```
var productOptions=new Array();
        productOptions['color']="test1";
        productOptions['size]="test2";
```

i DONT get the productOptions

Any help plz

Answer (score 9):

### Solution first

Make `productOptions` an `Object` instead of an `Array` and use `jQuery.extend()` to merge the `productOptions` with the rest of the data to be used in the ajax request.

```
var productOptions = new Object();
productOptions['color']="test1";
productOptions['size']="test2";

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "test.js",
  dataType: "script",
  data: jQuery.extend({action: 'add'}, productOptions)
});
```

Yields `GET test.js?_=randomjQueryNumber&action=add&color=test1&size=test2`

---

### The lengthy explanation

Your problem mainly originates from the error you made assuming the `Array` object is the same as an associative array. An array has only a number of entries which are accessed by a zero-based index. While an associative array consists of `(key, value)` pairs.

There is a simple test you can make

### Variant 1

```
var productOptions=new Array();
productOptions[0]="test1";
productOptions[1]="test2";
alert(productOptions.length); //yields 2
```

Note: If e.g. you replace `productOptions[0]` with `productOptions[4]` the alert will display 5!!

### Variant 2

```
var productOptions=new Array();
productOptions['color']="test1";
productOptions['size]="test2";
alert(productOptions.length); //yields 0
```

Variant 1 `productOptions[0]="test1";` behaves similar to `productOptions.push("test1");` (but isn't the same - check the *Note* under Variant 1 - `push` appends to the end of the array and the other syntax just sets the element at the specified index).

Variant 2 `productOptions['color']="test1";` doesn't even work on the "array"; This syntax does the same as it does with **every** javascript object, it sets the property `color` to the value `test1` on the object.

So if you use the syntax from the second variant you actually created an empty javascript array object with two properties `color` and `size`. Easy test

```
alert(productOptions.color); //yields test1
alert(productOptions.size); //yields test2
alert(productOptions[0]); //yields undefined
```

---

That's why the variant 1 works. There `productOptions` is a valid array and jQuery converts it to a query string which looks like this `option=test1&option=test2`.

The second variant is also handled correctly by jQuery as `option:productOptions` actually is the same as `option:new Array();`